# Should a kṣatriya always accept a gambling match by the opponent?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, iskcon, kshatriya

I base this question on a saying of Srila Prabhupada that goes like this:

> A kṣatriya is not supposed to refuse to battle or gamble when he is so invited by some rival party.
> Bhagavad Gita As It Is verses 37-38. In the purport.

So is this really true?

Note: I do know that Kṣatriyas should mostly ignore gambling but what if one dares them to a match then what should be his response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no such requirement:

[What do Hindu scriptures say about gambling?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/what-do-hindu-scriptures-say-about-gambling)

But in the case of Yudhistira, he seems to have made a vow not to refuse a gambling challenge:

> ‘Yudhishthira said, “It seems that some of the most feared rogues
> have assembled there. They are sure to play with the powers of maya.
> However, everything is under the control of the creator. I will not refuse
> to play with those rogues. O Vidura! I do not wish to go and gamble on
> King Dhritarashtra’s command. A father always has a son’s welfare in
> mind. Therefore, tell me what I should do. **I have no desire to
> gamble with Shakuni. But if the confident one challenges me in the
> sabha, I will never refuse, because that has been my eternal vow.”’**

Shakuni gives him a chance to back out, but Yudhistrira insists on playing:

> ‘Shakuni said, “O Yudhishthira! The learned triumph over non-learned
> only through trickery. That is how the wise triumph over the stupid, but
> people don’t call it trickery. In approaching me for the game, if you
> think that I will resort to trickery, if that is your fear, then refrain from
> the game.”
> ‘Yudhishthira replied, **“O king! Once challenged, I will not withdraw.**
> That is the vow I have taken. Fate is the powerful one and we are in the
> power of destiny. Who in this assembly will I play with? What is the
> counter-stake? Let the gambling begin.”