# Are there any instances in scriptures where a human reached other lokas beyond Swarga with their physical bodies?

Tags: yoga, body, lokas

In Hinduism, there are [several](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39887/661) lokas, such as Satya (Brahma), Tapa, Jana, Mahar, Svar (Svarga), Bhuvar, Bhu, Atala, Vitala, Sutala, Talatala, Mahatala, Rasatala, and Patala. It is known that human beings can reach other lokas, especially superior ones (urdhva lokas), *through their subtle bodies* rather than their physical bodies. There are exceptions, like the case of [Yudhishthira](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46500/661) and a few others, who reached Swarga loka with their physical bodies, though this is not common. However, I have not come across any examples of humans reaching urdhva lokas beyond Swarga, i.e., Mahar, Jana, Tapa, or Satya, with their physical bodies in the scriptures.

Are there any instances in scriptures in which a human reaches other urdhva lokas, beyond swaraga, with their physical bodies?

Please note that I am specifically looking for instances in the scriptures that **explicitly mention reaching other lokas with physical bodies**. Instances where it is merely mentioned that someone traveled to Brahma loka or other realms without specifying the body of travel are not required.

Comment: I think Kakudmi and his daughter reached Brahmaloka and returned and his daughter married with Balarama..

Comment: @Tezz I checked it, but no where I know mentioning that it is by physical body.  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40823/661

Comment: They traveled via physical body. Thats why when they got back yugas had changed, and Revati was manifold taller than others in Dwapar Yuga

Comment: @Carmensandiego Not necessarily. They can take a new body of same form. It is evident from the story of Lila in Yoga Vasista.

Comment: what do you mean by new body of same form ? you mean they got back in dwapar yuga and found bodies belonging to their yuga that they took over ?

Comment: @Carmensandiego The old physical bodies may not be extant while they take on new physical bodies. But the subtle body remains same without any loss in smrithi.

Comment: @Carmensandiego I am not denying your argument. It can be true, but not explicit. I know several instances from scriptures where the actual physical body by which they did yoga to reach other lokas will not be extant and they take new bodies of same form. So, I am searching for exact and explicit statements saying that they travlled by physical body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! what to speak of Satya Lok, once Arjuna went to Vaikhunta to bring back the Brahman's sons.

checkout shreemad bhagwatam [10.89.46](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/89/46/) - [10.89.61](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/89/advanced-view/#bb75983)

> Having thus advised Arjuna, the Supreme Personality of Godhead had
> Arjuna join Him on His divine chariot, and together they set off
> toward the west.
>
> The Lord’s chariot passed over the seven islands of the middle
> universe, each with its ocean and its seven principal mountains. Then
> it crossed the Lokāloka boundary and entered the vast region of total
> darkness
>
> In that darkness the chariot’s horses — Śaibya, Sugrīva, Meghapuṣpa and Balāhaka — lost their way. Seeing them in this condition, O best of the Bhāratas, Lord Kṛṣṇa, the supreme master of all masters of yoga, sent His Sudarśana disc before the chariot. That disc shone like thousands of suns.
>
> The Lord’s Sudarśana disc penetrated the darkness with its blazing effulgence. Racing forward with the speed of the mind, it cut through the fearsome, dense oblivion expanded from primeval matter, as an arrow shot from Lord Rāma’s bow cuts through His enemy’s army
>
> Following the Sudarśana disc, the chariot went beyond the darkness and reached the endless spiritual light of the all pervasive brahmajyoti. As Arjuna beheld this glaring effulgence, his eyes hurt, and so he shut them.
>
> From that region they entered a body of water resplendent with huge waves being churned by a mighty wind. Within that ocean Arjuna saw an amazing palace more radiant than anything he had ever seen before. Its beauty was enhanced by thousands of ornamental pillars bedecked with brilliant gems.
>
> In that palace was the huge, awe-inspiring serpent Ananta Śeṣa. He shone brilliantly with the radiance emanating from the gems on His thousands of hoods and reflecting from twice as many fearsome eyes. He resembled white Mount Kailāsa, and His necks and tongues were dark blue.
>
> Arjuna then saw the omnipresent and omnipotent Supreme Personality of Godhead, Mahā-Viṣṇu, sitting at ease on the serpent bed. His bluish complexion was the color of a dense rain cloud, He wore a beautiful yellow garment, His face looked charming, His broad eyes were most attractive, and He had eight long, handsome arms. His profuse locks of hair were bathed on all sides in the brilliance reflected from the clusters of precious jewels decorating His crown and earrings. He wore the Kaustubha gem, the mark of Śrīvatsa and a garland of forest flowers. Serving that topmost of all Lords were His personal attendants, headed by Sunanda and Nanda; His cakra and other weapons in their personified forms; His consort potencies Puṣṭi, Śrī, Kīrti and Ajā; and all His various mystic powers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But where it is mentioned that they did it with their physical bodies only?